# Is there a better algorithm to find connected clusters?

Tags: c++, graph, tree, depth-first-search

I'd like to find a better algorithm to find connected clusters.

For example, if I input:
(8, 6),
(1, 8),
(3, 5)
, then there are two connected clusters: <1,6,8> and <3,5>.

I tried to do that using Depth First Search, but it spent too much time (several days) when the inputs are very very substantial.

By the way, I tried to use igraph library; it was faster, but memory leak happened, my computer got breakdown.

My code (DFS) is below.

```
#ifndef GRAPH_I_H
#define GRAPH_I_H

#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <queue>
#include <mechsys/linalg/matvec.h>

using namespace std;

class Graph_i
{
public:
    int NumOfFractures;
    Array<Array<int>> G;
    Array<int> Visited;

public:
    Graph_i(const int NumOfFractures_1, const Array<int> Connections);
    void DFS(int V, Array<int> &B);
    void CreateGraph_i(Array<Array<int>> &S);
};

inline Graph_i::Graph_i(const int NumOfFractures_1, const Array<int> Connections)
{
    NumOfFractures = NumOfFractures_1;

    G.resize(NumOfFractures);

    for (int i = 0; i < NumOfFractures; ++i)
        G[i].resize(NumOfFractures);

    for (int i = 0; i < NumOfFractures; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < NumOfFractures; ++j)
            G[i][j] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Connections.Size() / 2; ++i)
    {
        G[Connections[2 * i]][Connections[2 * i + 1]] = 1;
        G[Connections[2 * i + 1]][Connections[2 * i]] = 1;
    }

    Visited.resize(NumOfFractures);
    for (int i = 0; i < NumOfFractures; ++i)
    {
        Visited[i] = 0;
    }
}

inline void Graph_i::DFS(int V, Array<int> &B)
{
    Visited[V] = 1;
    B.Push(V);
    for (int i = 0; i < NumOfFractures; ++i)
    {
        if (Visited[i] == 0 && G[V][i] == 1)
            DFS(i, B);
    }
}

inline void Graph_i::CreateGraph_i(Array<Array<int>> &S)
{
    if (S.Size() != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error! ListOfClusters should be empty array!\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < NumOfFractures; ++i)
    {
        if (Visited[i] == 0)
        {
            Array<int> A;
            DFS(i, A);

            S.Push(A);
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

Main function (this is just one time loop; actually, in my code, there are many loops; and I have used OpenMP):

```
#include <Graph_i.h>


int main()
{
    Array<int> Connections; //this is the input, containing pairs, e.g., 1,2,1,3,5,6; so,  <1,2,3> is a connected cluster, <5,6> is also a cluster; so, I need algorithm to identify them  
    //size of this array can be very very large

    Array< Array<int> > Listofclusters;// this two order array is used to recode connected clusters

    Graph_i G(Connections.Size(),   Connections);

    G.CreateGraph_i(Listofclusters);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: DFS is a fine way to go about this. Maybe you're duplicating work that causes your spent time to be large? What does your code look like?

Comment: Thanks! I have added the code, please find it.

Comment: Can you add a small `main` function that shows how you use this?

Comment: sure, I have updated my question.

Comment: You're throwing away any benefit you get from the DFS (or even a BFS) by iterating through every vertex whenever you check any vertex. If you make each vertex aware of its connected vertices, then the iteration in the DFS will be much smaller.

Comment: do you mean Adjacent List?

Comment: `numoffractures` appears to be 2 times the population of the graph? you're making your final graph 4 times larger than it needs to be.

Comment: Your graph should really be of dimension `max(Connections) x max(Connections)` right?

Comment: No. if vertexes include 0-8 and connection is 1,2,1,3,6,8, then, graph dimension should be 9, and clusters are <1,2,3>, <6,8>, <4>, <5>, <7>.

Comment: Okay, then graph dimensions should be `(max(Connections) + 1) x (max(Connections) + 1)`

Comment: Also, I'd maintain a `std::vector<std::set<int>> adjacency_list` where `adjacency_list[i]` is the set of vertexes connected to vertex `i` (not including `i`). That will make your DFS much faster. You can populate the adjacency list while you're populating the graph. This really only makes a difference if the graph is sparse. If it's a fully connected graph, then you'll be iterating through every point anyway, and the adjacency list will just take up extra space. So you need to tailor your approach to the data you expect to see.

Comment: Since the size of the graph can be calculated from `Connections`, you should only accept the `Connections` array into the constructor. `NumberOfFractures` is extra data that you shouldn't rely on the user to send, since they can get it wrong.

Comment: Actually, I thought the size of the graph cannot be calculated from [Connections]. Provided vertexes 0-8, [Connections] is 1,2,1,3,4,5. So, clusters are <1,2,3>, <4,5>, <6>, <7> and <8>. That is to say, [Connections] just records connected vertex ID values. But anyhow, thanks for all your suggestions!!!!!!!